# Read from file and write to file string with leading spaces

Tags: bash

I want to copy lines from one file to another:

```
count=1
while read -r i
do    
    echo $i
    (( count++ ))
done < "file1" > file2
```

but I don't get any leading spaces in lines in file 2 if they were in file1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the value of `IFS` (internal field separator) will strip out those spaces.  By default it separates based on spaces and newlines, I believe.  A way around this is to temporarily set `IFS` equal to a newline.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="
"

count=1

while read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]
do
    echo $i 
    (( count++ ))
done < "file1" > file2

unset IFS
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question: in this loop if last string with text in original file is not followed by line break that is not copied to file2. What can I do about that?

Comment: I have edited my answer to account for that.  The value will have been read into the variable, but the while will exit.  This fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
sed -n p < file1 > file2 ; count=$(wc -l file2)
```

Comment: Thanks I've got to copy not all strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `line` command:

```
count=1
while i=$(line)
do    
    echo "$i"
    (( count++ ))
done < "file1" > file2
```

However, this is significantly slower than `read`, because `read` is a bash builtin and `line` is a executable.

Comment: Thank you. But, the only thing that I'm not on nix, but on windows. =)